# How to make mainMenu send all action to specific NSWindowController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsmenu, nswindowcontroller

Short answer is inside the title :)

Explaining: in my `MainMenu.xib` I have only *the Main Menu* of the application, that must be same for all `NSWindow`s I open. There is one particular `NSWindowController` that has, let me say, all answers about when menu item must be enabled (via `case`s on `selector` in `validateUserInterfaceItem`) and what to do with all actions. When `NSWindow` associated with that `NSWindowController` is currently focused, there is no problem, but as I focus on another `NSWindow` all menus are grayed.

I have this flow now: `MainMenu` is created by reference to it as Main nib into `info.plist`, then `AppDelegate` do some init stuff and create `MainWinController` with `MainWindow`, at some point `MainWinController` creates 1+ `DetailsWinController` with `DetailsWindow`. `AppDelegate` manage my custom menu by calling each time functions from `MainWinController`.

So, how can I force the responder chain to query always that particular `NSWindowController` (`MainWinController`)?

Comment: Have you considered adding the Controller in the InterfaceBuilder and link the menu action to it.

Comment: please, can you explain better what i need to do? I'm quite new to all this firstresponder/delegate staff...

Answer (score 0):

You don't give many details to go on, and it isn't clear what you are trying to achieve.

My first reaction is that if you want share Menu items why are you creating multiple windows rather than Views within your MainWindow?

Assuming both your MainWindow and DetailsWindow implement the same selectors you could direct Menu Actions to the First Responder

To add the DetailsWinController in the InterfaceBuilder drag an NSObject from the Object Library, then in Identity Inspector change its class to your DetailsWinController class.

If your Main Menu has different items for the DetailsWindow just connect these to the actions in that instance.

NOTE if you so this you should NOT create the DetailsWinController in code.
If you really want to do this in code you will need to add actions and targets to your menu in code.

Comment: Each new DetailsWindow created by an user action in MainWindow has it's own DetailsWinController. I can have even 50 DetailsWindow at time. How can i use a View instead of Window in this case?

Comment: I don't want to implement all selectors in DetailsWinController and other XxxWinControllers that can be created by MainWinController, because they will be all a redirects to MainWindowController...

So for now i'v implemented all selectors in AppDelegate and MainWinController, so when DetailsWin is active AppDelegate is part of ResponderChain and all work ok... But in this way all selectors of AppDelegate are _redirects_ to selectors in MainWinController.

What i want to do is insert in ResponderChain of mainMenu my MainWinController so i don't need to put redirect selectors in AppDelegate